# SyndicationFeed Item Author

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rss, syndication-feed

I am consuming an RSS feed and showing the 2 most recent entries on my website. I need to show the title, author and publish date and also link to the article url.

I have no problem shwing the title, publish date and linking to the article, but I have problem with the author's name.

After searching about the syndycationfeed object, I found that there is and Authors list based on every author tag in the rss feed. So I searched for the author tag in my Rss feed and found none. Instead, I found a dc:creator tag.

Is there a way I can push the content of the dc:creator tag into the authors list when I create my syndicationfeed or syndicationitems?

For reference, I used the code from http://buildingwebapps.blogspot.ca/2012/02/showing-rss-items-from-your-blog-on_22.html to make my controller action, passing a SyndicationFeed object as my model to my partialView instead of putting it into my viewbag.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to solve the problem itself, but I discovered that the feed I was cosuming had an alternative format accessible. That other format was using the atom standard and compied with the syndicationFeed object.